# Are lightbox type scripts redundant with retina screens?

Tags: css, lightbox, pixel, retina-display

Is an image displaying in a lightbox script (e.g. prettyPhoto, lightbox, thickbox, etc) affected by high pixel ratio devices?

For example, if I had an 800px wide image up in a lightbox, will it be shown at 800 CSS pixels or 800 actual pixels? To probe further, is an image displayed raw in the browser affected in the same way?

If images displayed with lightboxes are affected by retina screens, what's the solution? Simply link to a larger image? (assuming the script auto resizes images to fit in the viewport)

Perhaps someone needs to develop a new jQuery plugin. :)

Comment: "CSS pixels"? A pixel is a pixel; it's whatever your resolution makes it. AFAIK, the Retina displays are just high-DPI displays, and the OS scales up the GUI to remain a constant "real-life" size.

Comment: Not quite. There is now a difference between the pixels we use to set widths and text sizes and the actual pixels of the device. Zoom in to a page with any modern browser and this already happens. With the iPhone 4 or iPad 3 there is a pixel ratio of 2:1, meaning that images are scaled up and start looking fuzzy.